# Text not appearing on textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

To appear softkeyboard for android app i written textfield.needsSoftKeyboard = true and onclick on textfield call textfield.requestSoftKeyboard() method. keyboard is appearing..but the problem is text is not appearing on textfield...

Comment: here am using tlf textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is textfield loses focus.Finally I got solution.We have to set Focus for that tlf textfield like this.txtField.textFlow.interactionManager = new EditManager();
txtField.textFlow.interactionManager.selectRange(0, 0);
txtField.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense if you could post the code snippet here for further investigation. Other than that, it might be that your textfield loses focus for some reason so you may get your issue resolved by calling "stage.focus = textfield;". It could also be the case that there is a problem with font embedding or styles (e.g. white text on white background). Make sure the textfield shows text at all by passing a prefilled text to it. There is currently also a bug, where Chinese and Japanese chars cannot be displayed on some Android devices (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3839647).

Comment: My code :Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;


username_txt.needsSoftKeyboard = true;

 username_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );


function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 
 username_txt.requestSoftKeyboard();
 stage.focus = username_txt;
 
}

Comment: Did you check that 1) the bug mentioned in my previous comment is not the source of the error 2) prefilled text does appear?

Comment: he means whether you have any text to show in the first place or not..ie `myTf.text = "text"` i also recommend setting `myTf.border = true` for debugging

Comment: prefilled text is appearing.@Jan@Marton Pallagi

Comment: For clasic textfield text appearing..but the problem with TLF textfield only.@Jan@MMarton Pallagi

Comment: This behavior sounds like it is a bug. Please fill a bug report@https://bugbase.adobe.com